# How to deploy rar/ear/war file to IBM Web Sphere Application Server 7.0 using maven?

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, application-server

How to deploy rar/ear/war file to IBM Web Sphere Application Server 7.0 using maven i.e. automatic deployment without any manual intervention?

Comment: I don't follow you on this Jonas and casperOne, The question is clear. bmk1977 has a JavaEE application built with Maven, that he wants to be deployed without having to start WAS, go on the web interface, and so on. Instead he'd like to "mvn was:deploy" or similar. It would also be helpful to do some testing. So, that's a real question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you google this? It is not trivial to deploy to Geronimo servers via Maven but there are many many ways and each require much configuration (I have done a lot of this) and Websphere 7.0 is based on Geronimo so I think you will have work to do. There are many plugins (geronimo specific from apache and things like Cargo http://cargo.codehaus.org/Deploying+to+a+running+container) but nothing I see for Web Sphere specifically.

This bloger has done it using the ANT plugin and calling the Web Sphere deploy scripts using Maven http://sdudzin.blogspot.com/2007/09/maven-2-and-websphere-automated-build.html

That should work

Comment: As far as I know, WebSphere Application Server Community Edition is based on Geronimo, WAS 7 isn't

Comment: Thank you so much, i don't know that IBM WebSphere Application Server is based on Geronimo. This helps lot.